# Shuffle PDF 2-up in shell

Tags: command-line, pdf

I want to make a new pdf from my old one: put portrait pages 1 & 2 on a landscape page 1, pages 3 & 4 on page 2, and so on.

`Preview.app` does this, but I need to do it in the shell.

`jPDFtweak.jar` also does this in GUI, but for no reason it fails to do it in terminal (for some of my files).

I do not know, how to use `lp` to print to pdf.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Coherent's](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) command line PDFs tools.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @IconDaemon,
the solution is like this:

```
cpdf -twoup-stack my-file.pdf -o out.pdf
cpdf -rotate 90 out.pdf -o out2.pdf
cpdf -scale-to-fit "210mm 297mm" out2.pdf -o my-file-collated.pdf
rm out.pdf out2.pdf
```